# Apache - How to add https to the following

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to add https:// to the following url:  http://www.createjobsforusa.org/donate

How can I do this in Apache?

Here's what I'm doing so far, but doesn't work:

```
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
  RewriteRule ^donate https://www.createjobsforusa.org/donate [R,L]
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the rewrite engine?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?donate https://www.createjobsforusa.org/donate [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try this condition: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$`

Answer (score 0):

Please give this code a try:

```
# once per htaccess file
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^donate/?$ https://www.createjobsforusa.org/donate
```